# Multipling All Numbers In an Array by the Same Multiplier, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javascript and I am trying to do this and I am stuck:

Write a function to multiply each element in an array by some value. The function must have this header:

```
function multiply(list, multiplier)
```

If the multiply function were called like this:

```
var list = [ 17, 8, 9, 5, 20 ];
var products = multiply(list, 3);
```

The multiply function would return an array with these values:

```
[ 51, 24, 27, 15, 60 ]
```

This is what I have so far.

```
function getNumbers (){
    var n0 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n0").value);
    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
    var n3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n3").value);
    var n4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n4").value);
    var multiplier = parseFloat(document.getElementById("multiplier").value);
    var list = [n0, n1, n2, n3, n4];
    var products = multiply(list, multiplier);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = products;
}

function = multiply(list, multiplier) {
    var products;
    products = list.map(function (list){
    return list * multiplier;
    });
    return products;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: so, where is problem? in your code i see just one typo _function = multiply(list, multiplier)_ remove `=` here, and all work

Comment: You know you're trying to set an array as the `innerHTML` of an element ?

Comment: @adeneo, and what wrong with it? :-)

Comment: @Grundy - Everything? Modern browsers will probably display the array, but it's still not the expected type.

Comment: @adeneo, but here just work impicit conversion to string and all ok. why you think this _not the expected type_ - expected type - string, and array converted to string - so all ok

Comment: @Grundy - And again, modern browsers will stringify the array if you make the mistake of assigning an array to `innerHTML`, but the expected type is still string, even if modern browsers will fix your mistakes.

Comment: @adeneo, if i not mistaken, this feature work in any browser, can you provide sample where is not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97104/discussion-between-grundy-and-adeneo).

Comment: Thank you so much. I somehow kept missing the = sign between the function multiply(list, multiplier). I feel like such an idiot for not catching this.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
function multiply(list, multiplier) {
    return list.map(function (item){
        return item * multiplier;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change into this in your `multiply` function:

```
function multiply(list, multiplier) {
  return list.map(function (list){
    return list * multiplier;
  });
}
```

or you can change into this:

```
function multiply(list, multiplier) {
  $.each(list, function(index, value) {
    list[index] = value * multiplier;
  });
  return list;
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: You're mapping, but not returning anywhere

Comment: That's not valid js. -1

Comment: I have updated the code. Thanks for your correction @Oleander.

Comment: Nice. I removed my -1

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here: `function = multiply(list, multiplier) {`
                                                   ^^^

Remove this sign `=` and your code work ok.